# convert codes vb 6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

i dont know how to convert this codes.

this code for sub main

```
Public Sub main()
    On Error Resume Next
    frmsplash.Show
    Open App.Path & "/joel.txt" For Input As #1
    Input #1, serverhost
    Input #1, mydatabasename
    Input #1, myusername
    Input #1, mypassword
    Input #1, mysqlport
    Close #1

    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=" & Trim(serverhost) & ";Port=" & Trim(mysqlport) & ";Database=" & Trim(mydatabasename) & "; User=" & Trim(myusername) & ";Password=" & Trim(mypassword) & ";Option=3;"
    cn.Open

    If cn.State = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable  to connect to database", vbCritical
        frmconnect.Show
        frmsplash.Hide
    Exit Sub
```

and this code for create connection

```
Private Sub cmdcreate_Click()
    Open App.Path & "\joel.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, txtserver.Text
    Print #1, txtschema.Text
    Print #1, txtuser.Text
    Print #1, txtpassword.Text
    Print #1, txtport.Text
    Close #1
    Unload Me
    Call main
End Sub
```

im trying to create a connection string.. submain.. textfile...

Comment: What have you tried and what bit specifically are you stuck on? Rather than converting code, you will have more like by actually learning the language and rewriting in a structure more suitable for the platform.

Comment: i convert that code in vb.net but i got an error...

Comment: What error? on what bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `system.io.textreader` to read a lines from a file:

```
dim tr as system.io.textreader = new system.io.streamreader(file)
dim val as string = tr.readline
```

Use `system.io.textwriter` to write a line to a file:

```
dim tw as system.io.textwriter = new system.io.streamwriter(file)
tw.writeline(val)
```

As for the data access use something from system.data. You'll need to google for that 'cos I'm writing this on a phone and have just lost patience :-)